# Running `sudo nginx -t` on server instance in Amazon Aws shows error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server, cloud, vps

I have a server instance in Amazon Aws, and using Nginx. When I run `sudo nginx -t`, it shows me this:

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.perfactors.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.perfactors.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

**Even though I don't have a domain as blog.perfactors.com, It is trying to find a SSL certificate for that.**

Please suggest me a solution for that.

Comment: are u logged in as root user? .pem file error happens when you not uses root user